# When the event handlers are bind in ASP.NET Lifecyle

Tags: .net, lifecycle

Lets assume I have a drowdownlist and it has a OnSelectedIndexChanged event. What I want to know is which section of the lifecyle is responsible to bind this event to the method. Where is this happening?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

Why do you ask?

If the event handler is specified in the markup then the event handler will be wired up at the same time as all other properties - as the the control is instantiated, i.e. between the [PreInit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.preinit.aspx) and [Init](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.init.aspx) events.

See [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) for reference.